# Does such a function exist ? $\forall \alpha > 0\ (\ln(x))^\alpha =o (f(x))$, $\forall \beta > 0\ (f(x)) =o (x^\beta)$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

$f : \Bbb R_+^* \rightarrow   \Bbb R_+^* $

$\forall  \alpha > 0\ (\ln(x))^\alpha =o (f(x))$, and $\forall  \beta > 0$ $(f(x)) =o (x^\beta)$

The $o$ are in + $\infty$
I don't really see how to deal with this problem; does someone have a clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can see that $\log f(x)$ should grow slower than $\log x$, but faster than $\log \log x$. Something between those two are $(\log x)^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Avoiding the problem that $\log x < 0$ for $x < 1$, we can pick

$$f_{\alpha}(x) = \exp \bigl((\log (x+1))^{\alpha}\bigr),\quad \alpha \in (0,1).$$

Comment: An example of a function that grows like this is the running time of the quadratic sieve factorization algorithm.

Comment: @DanBrumleve  what does o mean here?   I know the zero version but not $\infty$